# Constructing a recursive sequence (Terence Tao Analysis II Theorem 1.5.8)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $Y$ be a subset of metric space $(X,d)$ and $Y$ isn't compact (in terms of finite open cover). I need to construct a recursive sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $Y$ such that $y_{n}$ is atleast $\epsilon$ far apart from all of the previous elements of the sequence. (where $\epsilon$ is a positive real). Actually I am assuming that $Y$ is sequentially compact but not compact in terms of finite open cover. Here I am proceeding by contradiction.
Since $Y\neq \emptyset$ thus we take an element $s$ from $Y$ and assign it to $y_{1}$
$$y_{1}=s$$
Now I want to assign  $y_{n+1}$ a point from the set $$\{y\in Y:y\notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_{X,d} (y_{i},\epsilon)\}$$I know that this set isn't empty as each ball is contained in one of the set from the open cover $\{G_{\alpha}:\alpha \in I\}$ and the whole of Y contained in the union  of these finite balls would imply that a finite cover exists.
My Question is how could I assing a point from  the set mentioned above to $y_{n+1}$.

Comment: You are fixing an $\epsilon$ and trying to find $(y_n)$. That is not possible always. What you are asked to prove is the existence of some $\epsilon$ and some $(y_n)$ such that $d(y_n,y_m) \geq \epsilon$ whenever $n \neq m$. Try to prove this by contradiction.

Comment: I know that such an $\epsilon$ exists

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . What if  $X=Y=[0,1)$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$?....

Comment: This Y isn't sequentially compact